# How to (legally) remove Singstar from PS3

Tags: ps3, singstar

There is a lot of add ons for PS3 CFW that help removing Singstar, but I like PSN, and would not risk to be banned just for this.

But this game annoy me, and apart from petition (which obviously led to nothing), I didn't see anything to remove singstar.

Is there any legal way to remove at least the icon of Singstar from the XMB?

Comment: Doubtful but this is my own speculation since I do not work for Sony. But the same thing with the Netflix icon on the movies section. I have to skip over it every time I want to use other video services. Someone likely paid a bit of money to get that icon to always be there as a form of advertising.

Comment: Get an import PlayStation 3 from somewhere outside of Europe? Not really practical, but probably the only the solution that doesn't require hacking your PS3.

Comment: I wouldn't mind getting rid of it too, it's practically useless cause songs like Black★Rocker Shooter or SOMEONE ELSE aren't in it's listing.

Comment: @James: I believe it s more "Hey look, even barebone PS3 have Netflix and a game free", I don t care about Netflix, but Singstar is annoying.

Comment: @RossRidge: It would be a solution if I wasn t short of money. And buying a PS3 because there is one icon too much seems... excessive.

Comment: As I said, it's not really a practical solution, just the only solution.

Comment: I just won't buy a Sony product ever again.  I am sick of their rubbish attitude towards their customers.

Answer (score 1):

Not an ideal fix, and probably less legal than desired, but the Singstar icon is not present in the PS3 XMB when used with a non-"European" PSN account which is easy to create under a new Profile using an American address during signup.

As I said, not ideal as you are creating a whole new PSN ID just to avoid seeing the Singstar "ad" under that profile only.